# Can't filter whitespace, Query returns all users

Tags: php, html, sql, filter

I have a User Interface where users can type in first name and last name of a person.
As long as i enter nothing in the Search Boxes, no users will be found. But as soon as i enter a white space, every user in the Database is returned. I trim the Input strings and check for whitespaces:

```
if (isset($_GET['lastname'])) {
    $lastname_value = trim($_GET['lastname']);
    //This Line is only used for setting the Text again in the Search Box       
    $tpl->setVariable('ss-search-lastname-value', $lastname_value);
}
if(isset($_GET['firstname'])) {
    $firstname_value = trim($_GET['firstname']);
    $tpl->setVariable('ss-search-firstname-value',$firstname_value);
}
```

After that i compose the search Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT e.`user_id`, e.`firstname`, e.`lastname`, e.`email`
            FROM `employees` as e
            WHERE 1";
if($lastname_value!="") {
    $sql .=" AND e.`lastname` ='$lastname_value'";
}
if($firstname_value!="") {
    $sql .=" AND e.`firstname` ='$firstname_value'";
}
```

A normal search returns the expected user with the right first name and last name, if I enter nothing and start the Search, no results are returned. However a single whitespace in the Search Box and I get all users. How can I fix that?

Comment: I think the right approach is to not compose SQL as strings since you are open to injection attacks.  Redo it with parameters and perhaps you won't have the problem anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first decide whether or not you would like to search:

```
$doSearch = false;
$hasLastname = $lastname_value != "";
$hasFirstname = $firstname_value != "";
$doSearch = $hasLastname || $hasFirstname;

if ($doSearch)
{
    $sql = "SELECT e.`user_id`, e.`firstname`, e.`lastname`, e.`email`
            FROM `employees` as e
            WHERE 1";
    if($lastname_value!="") {
        $sql .=" AND e.`lastname` ='$lastname_value'";
    }
    if($firstname_value!="") {
        $sql .=" AND e.`lastname` ='$firstname_value'";
    }
    ...
}
```